# Failed to start the Kernel on Jupyter in VS code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, virtual-environment

I am trying to use a Jupyter notebook in VS Code. I made a virtual environment but keep this error occurred and I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

I have tried several ways from other question posts.

**What I have done**

- `pip uninstall pyzmq`
  `pip install pyzmq==19.0.2`
- uninstall anaconda and reinstall it
- run VS Code as administrator

here is the error log.

`Error 13:34:31: Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 127.0.0.1:9000`

`Error 13:34:31: failed to create INotebook in kernel, UI Disabled = false [Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 127.0.0.1:9000`